# JavaScript onfocus attribute and key events

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, focus

I am trying to simulate an keyinput in JavaScript on a textbox, in Firefox. The textbox has an `onfocus=" this.value='' "` attribute. A simulation + my code can be found at

Working code:

```
var divy = document.getElementById("eventListener");
divy.focus();

var inputText = '';

for(var i = 0; i < ('asd').length; i++)
{
   var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
   event.initKeyEvent ('keydown', true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, 0) 
   divy.dispatchEvent(event);

   inputText += ('asd').charAt(i);

   var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
   event.initKeyEvent ('keypress', true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, ('asd').charCodeAt(i)) 
   divy.dispatchEvent(event);
   divy.value = inputText;

   var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
   event.initKeyEvent ('keyup', true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 0, 0) 
   divy.dispatchEvent(event);
}


divy.blur();
```

My question is, how to properly simulate the input (without jquery!) so that the second textbox doesn't have an empty value. And also as the focus event is only once thrown, why gets the value erased each time.

**UPDATE:**

As I thought that the divy.focus(); Method might need some time to execute the onfocus event in attributes, I set up a timeout to send the key events, using:

```
windows.setTimeout("fireKeys2()", 5000);
```

But this also does not seem to work. The test is located here
http://jsfiddle.net/hPBNA/23/

UPDATE 2:

I figured out the problem myself, it seems like if element.value has been set to '' this way (element.value = '') element.setAttribute('value', someText) is not able to change it. Accessing the element.value property instead gave me the right results.

Tested in Firefox 22. Don't know if its reproducible on other versions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem myself, it seems like if element.value has been set to '' this way (element.value = ''), element.setAttribute('value', someText) is not able to change it. Accessing the element.value property instead gave me the right results.

Tested in Firefox 22. Don't know if its reproducible on other versions.

John